# Select vertical table to horizontal table SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following table:

```
-------------------------------------------
ID     Group     myDate       Value
-------------------------------------------
1      A         2014-06-01   100
2      A         2014-06-02   200
3      A         2014-06-03   300
4      B         2014-06-01   50
5      B         2014-06-02   100
6      B         2014-06-03   125
```

I want to have the following result:

```
-------------------------------------------
myDate       Value     myDate      Value
-------------------------------------------
2014-06-01   100       2014-06-01  50   
2014-06-02   200       2014-06-02  100
2014-06-03   300       2014-06-03  125
```

So I want to make it horizontal view base on Group field.
Does anyone know How to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: how many rows on the table might have the same date? always just 2, or could there be 3, 4, 5 etc. ?

Comment: also are the group values predictable (A, B, C, etc.) or is there much variation?

Comment: @BrianDeMilia, Actually only A, B, and C.. But let say it could be more that that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fiddle:**
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/df9dc/1/0

```
select      min(case when grp = 'A' then mydate end) as mydate1,
            min(case when grp = 'A' then value end) as value1,
            min(case when grp = 'B' then mydate end) as mydate2,
            min(case when grp = 'B' then value end) as value2
from        tbl
group by    mydate
```

Will be cumbersome if you have a lot of groups but if there are just a couple more it shouldn't be too hard to add the necessary case statements for the others.

Comment: Cheers mate,, it works! But need to find out, How if the Groups is more than that.

Comment: But this is not the best approach as if u have the list grows it would make your code cumbersome so its better to go for pivot :)

Comment: even with pivot you would still have to add to the code for additional groups, it is not dynamic. @Haminteu to add case statements for additional groups just copy and paste the ones already there but change A or B to C or whatever the next group is